# How can I solve this database problem?[json]

Tags: json

Here is the **traceback error**
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 6 column 3 (char 92)
**Json file**

```
{

    "params": {
        "local_server": "True",
        "local_uri": "mysql.connector.connect(host =
        "localhost"
        ",user = "
        "root"
        ",password = "
        ",database = "
        "CodingThunder"
        )",
        "fb_url": "https://www.facebok.com/codingthunder",
        "tw_url": "https://twitter.com/coding thunder",
        "gh_url": "https:/github.com/coding thunder"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is broken, missing comma in line 6, also it has other formatting problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
"params": {
    "local_server": "True",
    "local_uri": "mysql.connector.connect(host=localhost,user=root,password=,database=CodingThunder)",
    "fb_url": "https://www.facebok.com/codingthunder",
    "tw_url": "https://twitter.com/coding thunder",
    "gh_url": "https:/github.com/coding thunder"
}
```